# How do I share a realm or realm object with multiple user using realm mobile platform?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is it possible to share between different users the same object? this way even though they have their private objects they can share/collaborate on some of those. How would I do that?

Comment: an example would be: how do user A and User B collaborate on a book?

Answer (score 1):

Katsumi from Realm here.

Realm Object Server supports access control on Realms, such that multiple users can share a Realm. Thus if a Realm is a chat thread, you would need to set the permissions for each user in the thread to have access to that Realm. The current version of the developer edition of Realm Object Server doesn't include client APIs to change permissions, but this will be coming in a couple weeks during the beta period.

Comment: so you would be able to share a whole realm? not a single object in your own?

Comment: @Massimo Both will be supported in the future. But sharing a whole Realm file first, then sharing partial Realm objects will be supported.